# How to visit multiple menus say a website has 5 menus, and also visit each of their sub menus by clicking them using selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm not able to find a solution to visit menus and sub-menus while automating an website, I can visit them but the problem is the code is like 500-700 lines. I need a solution like using for loop for the problem.

I expected the driver to visit the menus and it's sub menus but I was only able to visit a single menu and a single sub menu which is present in the first menu.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.